# javaScript_Recursive_Function _function sumToOne(num)

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to implement `sumToOne(num)` which sums a given integer’s digits repeatedly until the sum is only one digit - and return that one-digit result.

Example: `sumToOne(928)` returns 1, because 9+2+8 = 19, then 1+9 = 10, then 1+0 = 1.

Everything is working fine, but I wasn't able to call back `recursion(sum);`.

Could anyone point out what I am missing cause I am new in recursive function logic, please ?

```
function sumToOne(num) {

  const nxNum = String(num).split('');
  const length = nxNum.length;
  let sum = 0;

  let recursion = (sum) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      sum += + +nxNum[i];
    }
    if (sum < 10) {
      return sum;
    }
    recursion(sum);
  }
}
sumToOne(928);
```

Comment: Why even have the `recursion` function? You can call `sumToOne` recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes having an inner function helps with recursion, but not in this case.

If the number passed as an argument has at least two digits, we can use our function again and only return the actual number (breaking recursion) once it's just one digit (`< 10`):

```js
function sumToOne(num) {
    if (num < 10) return num;

    const nxNum = String(num).split('');
    const length = nxNum.length;
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += +nxNum[i];
    }

    return sumToOne(sum);
}
```

Notice that you can convert this function to a one-liner by using `Array.prototype.reduce` (if readability is not crucial):

```js
const sumToOne = n => n < 10 ? n : sumToOne(String(n).split('').map(Number).reduce((s, d) => s + d));
```

Comment: Thank you Robo Robok !! I don't know why my previous thank note disappeared suddenly.. Maybe we were blocked by the moderator because we were too civil.. On a more serious thought, both of your solutions helped pretty Much !! Kudos to you !

Answer (score -1):

Variables declared with the let keyword can have Block Scope.

Variables declared inside a block {} cannot be accessed from outside the block:

Example

```
{
  let x = 2;
}
```

// x can NOT be used here

Try your code using the var keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Initially it was with a var but still wasn't working.

Comment: Don't encourage using `var`. It's pretty much obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

Recursive solutions exist everywhere!

```js
const sumToOne = (n = 0) =>
  n < 10
    ? n
    : sumToOne(sum(digits(n)))
    
const sum = ([ n = 0, ...more ]) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? n
    : n + sum(more)

const digits = (n = 0) =>
  n < 10
    ? [ n ]
    : [ ...digits(Math.floor(n / 10)), n % 10 ]

console.log(sumToOne(928)) // 1
console.log(sumToOne(111)) // 3
console.log(sumToOne(999)) // 9
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! I would just need to you explain why n would be undefined (stated as a precautionary measure?! how could it be called empty?) and 10 >> 0, please .. The rest was pretty clear and neat !!

Comment: Hi @Kamilović, you raise a good question. Those areas were too cryptic and are hopefully fixed in an update I made to the post.